If $\mathcal G^{(0)}$ is open then $r$ is locally injective.
Let $\mathcal G$ be a topological groupoid i.e. $\mathcal G$ is a non-empty set endowed with a locally compact Hausdorff, second countable topology together with a distinguished subset $\mathcal G^{(2)} \subseteq \mathcal G \times \mathcal G$, a multiplication map $m : \mathcal G^{(2)} \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ defined by $(\alpha, \beta) \mapsto \alpha \beta$ and an inverse map $\iota : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ defined by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha^{-1}$ such that the following conditions are satisfied $:$

$(1)$ $(\alpha^{-1})^{-1} = \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal G$ i.e. $\iota$ is an involution.
$(2)$ If $(\alpha, \beta)$ and $(\beta, \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ then $(\alpha, \beta \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ and $(\alpha \beta, \gamma) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}.$ Moreover, the multiplication is associative i.e. $\alpha (\beta \gamma) = (\alpha \beta) \gamma.$
$(3)$ $(\gamma, \gamma^{-1}) \in \mathcal G^{(2)}$ for all $\gamma \in \mathcal G$ and for all $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathcal G^{(2)},$ we have $(\alpha \beta) \beta^{-1} = \alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1} (\alpha \beta) = \beta.$
$(4)$ The multiplication map $m$ and the inverse map $\iota$ are continuous.

Define a set $\mathcal G^{(0)} : = \{\gamma \gamma^{-1}\ |\ \gamma \in \mathcal G \}.$ This set is called the unit space of $\mathcal G$ and the elements of this set are called units of $\mathcal G.$ Consider the maps $r : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G^{(0)}$ defined by $\gamma \mapsto \gamma \gamma^{-1}$ and $s : \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G^{(0)}$ defined by $\gamma \mapsto \gamma^{-1} \gamma.$  If $\mathcal G$ is a topological groupoid, then both the maps $r$ and $s$ are continuous. The maps $r$ and $s$ are called the range and the source map respectively.
Thomsen claimed that if $\mathcal G^{(0)}$ is open then given $\gamma \in \mathcal G$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\gamma$ such that for all $\alpha, \beta \in U$ with $r(\alpha) = r(\beta),$ we have $\alpha^{-1} \beta \in \mathcal G^{(0)}$ using continuity of the operations in a topological groupoid. But I don't have any idea as to how to get hold of such an open neighbourhood $U$ of $\gamma.$
Any suggestion regarding this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

I think I got an idea which I elaborate in the following $:$
Consider the set $$\mathcal G^{(1)} : = \{(\alpha, \beta)\ |\ r(\alpha) = r(\beta) \} \subseteq \mathcal G \times \mathcal G.$$ Then $\mathcal G^{(1)}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal G^{(2)}$ via the self-invertible continuous map $\iota \times \text {id}.$ Since $\mathcal G$ is a topological groupoid, by the continuity of the multiplication map it follows that $\mathcal G^{(2)}$ is open in $\mathcal G$ and hence so is $\mathcal G^{(1)},$ as they both are homeomorphic to each other. Now consider the map $\varphi : \mathcal G^{(1)} \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ defined by $\varphi : = m \circ (\iota \times \text {id}).$ Then clearly $\varphi$ is continuous. Since the unit space $\mathcal G^{(0)}$ is open, it follows that $\varphi^{-1} \left (\mathcal G^{(0)} \right )$ is open in $\mathcal G^{(1)}$ (and, hence in $\mathcal G$ as well). Note that $(\alpha, \alpha) \in \varphi^{-1} \left (\mathcal G^{(0)} \right )$ for all $\alpha \in \mathcal G,$ as $\alpha^{-1} \alpha \in \mathcal G^{(0)}.$ In particular, $(\gamma, \gamma) \in \varphi^{-1} \left (\mathcal G^{(0)} \right ).$ Hence we can get hold of open neighbourhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $\gamma$ in $\mathcal G$ such that $$\left (U_1 \times U_2 \right ) \cap \mathcal G^{(1)} \subseteq \varphi^{-1} \left (\mathcal G^{(0)} \right ).$$ Then $U : = U_1 \cap U_2$ will do the job for us. $\square$
